# Maven failsafe plugin not firing integration test

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

Could not understand this is happening. When I run,

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test
```

it fires my integration tests (test ending with ***IT.java) as first. Then, when I execute immediately the same command, it says "No tests to run".

Any help of information would be appreciated. Below is my pom.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.19.1</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>integration-test</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>verify</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>verify</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Don't run `mvn failsafe:integration-test`, but `mvn clean verify`...

Comment: @Tunaki - Thanks !. But, **mvn clean verify** fires only _units tests_ not _integration tests_.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your failsafe plugin as described in http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

then `mvn clean verify` should do the trick (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html) you should use

```
mvn verify
```

because " when running integration tests, you should invoke Maven with the (shorter to type too) mvn verify rather than trying to invoke the `integration-test` phase directly, as otherwise the post-integration-test phase will not be executed."

Note that if you have errors in your unittests (the `test` phase) the build will stop there and the integration tests will not be run (check the [Maven Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) for what is run when.