# Multi Module Pom Java Project Won't Run My Integration Tests

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have reviewed similar questions here --> [Maven fail-safe not executing tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387679/maven-fail-safe-not-executing-tests) and here --> [Maven failsafe plugin not firing integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621207/maven-failsafe-plugin-not-firing-integration-test) and they haven't fixed my issue.

My question is slightly different. When I run the mvn clean install command in my Eclipse Run configurations it seems to invoke the java integrated test classes named UserGetRolesIT and UserSetRolesIT. However, it doesn't run any of the nested tests within the classes. Let me go through my project setup for reference.

My project directory setup:

```
AuthorizationMS  (project root dir)
|-- AuthorzationMS 
    |-- pom.xml  (project A with integration tests)
|-- AMS-Client
    |-- pom.xml (project B wih integration tests)
|-- pom.xml  (parent pom.xml)
```

Here is my parent pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.xxx.ams</groupId>
  <artifactId>AuthorizationMSParent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>AuthorizationMSParent</name>
  
  <modules>
    <module>AMS-Client</module> 
    <module>AuthorizationMS</module>
  </modules>
  
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  
  <repositories>
    .....
  </repositories>
  
  <dependencies>
     ....
  </dependencies>
```

Here is the project A pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxx.xxx.authms</groupId>
  <artifactId>AuthorizationMS</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>AuthorizationMS</name>
  
  <parent>
      <artifactId>AuthorizationMSParent</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.xxx.xxx.ams</groupId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  
  <repositories>
     ....
  </repositories>
  
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  
  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IT</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>none</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>verify</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <warName>AuthorizationMS</warName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

During the log output of the maven clean install run I see the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Jan 17, 2024 4:59:09 PM com.xxx.xxx.authms.data.service.CloudantServiceManager init
INFO: CloudantServiceManager | init method start
Jan 17, 2024 4:59:10 PM com.xxx.xxx.authms.data.service.CloudantServiceManager init
INFO: CloudantServiceManager | init total: 762
Running com.xxx.xxx.authms.test.UserGetRolesIT
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in com.xxx.xxx.authms.test.UserGetRolesIT
Running com.xxx.xxx.authms.test.UserSetRolesIT
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in com.xxx.xxx.authms.test.UserSetRolesIT
```

Here is the code of one of the integration test classes. I haven't included all the import, package statements, and all the nested tests, but I think I give enough to get the gist.

```
public class UserGetRolesIT {

    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static AuthorizationDataService authDataService = AuthorizationDataService.getInstance();

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Test Getting Roles")
    class TestGettingUserRolesIT {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @DisplayName("getRoles valid users")
        @ValueSource(strings = { "user@xxx.com", "Some Name/Place/Compnay", "David Luck/Somewhere/Company", 
                "Newton Apple/Place/Company", "user2@xxx.com", "" })
        void isUserFoundIT(String userId) throws AuthException {
            assertTrue(authDataService.getRole(userId).getRole() != null, userId + " is not being found");
        }

      @Test
        @DisplayName("getRoles RoleByIds")
        void getRolesByIds() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, AuthException {
            URL testFileURL = UserGetRolesIT.class.getResource("/roles/GetRoles_Role_By_Ids.json");
            String content = Files.readString(Paths.get(testFileURL.toURI()));
            
            // Turn our test .json file into a real object
            AuthorizationData info = gson.fromJson(content, AuthorizationData.class);
            Map<String, Role> rolesMap = authDataService.getRolesByDeliverableIds(info.getUserId(), info.getDeliverableIds());
            assertTrue(!rolesMap.isEmpty(), "");
            assertTrue(rolesMap.containsValue(Role.READER), "Response came back false!");
        }
        
}
```

The punchline is it seems to invoke the class but not run the tests. What am I missing?
-Doug

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own issue. It was the ancient version of maven failsafe plugin I was using. I must have copied and pasted from some past project. Moving to the 3.2.5 resolved the issue and the tests are now running as expected.